# Strange behaviour of Rmarkdown. It stops during execution for no apparent reason

Tags: r-markdown

I have recently run into a very strange issue with Rmarkdown. When I run a chunk that takes a few minutes Rmarkdown just stops at some point. This does not happen every time, but often enough. The chunk runs some Rcpp code. I can't produce an example because the routines run are quite lengthy, sorry. I am attaching a screenshot that shows the progress of the chunk, but also shows that Rmarkdown has stopped (no red button). When it stops it also does not redraw the viewer.
[image]

Comment: I have now verified that the issue lies with the use of Rcpp. I have the exact same routines running pure R and Rcpp. The problem happens only when the Rcpp version is used. Of course I wrote those because they run much faster, so I really would like to be able to use them.  The Rcpp routines and the R routines work otherwise just fine and yield the exact same results.

Comment: I have now rewritten the routine entirely in Rcpp, and now it also works fine. So the issue seems to be switching between R and Rcpp